# how to check for a range within a set of non overlapping ranges in constant time

Tags: c, algorithm, hash, range

For example, consider a set of non-overlapping ranges.

```
      Range 1 - [100,150] 
      Range 2 - [180.200]
      Range 3 - [250,300]
```

Valid inputs can be `[100,110]`, `[115,130]`, `[185,195]`, `[250,300]`; these are all contained within one of the 3 ranges. The first two input ranges belong to range 1, the third belongs to range 2, and the last one belongs to range 3.

Invalid inputs (not contained inside one of the 3 ranges) include `[80,90]`, `[310,320]`, `[160,170]`, `[80,190]`, `[80,110]`, `[180,320]`, `[260,310]`.

The question of input range actually exists within that range is not a problem. I just want to know whether a given range fits in any of the particular range in a given range set.

Instead of linear and binary search to find this out,Is there any way we can do in constant time(using hashing or any techniques). If not constant time, a more optimal solution?

Comment: How large is maximum range?

Comment: Does the input always belong to a range?

Comment: I don't think you can do much better than O(logN) time with `bsearch()`, though if the number of ranges is small enough, a linear search might be OK.  Since the ranges are non-overlapping, they can simply be sorted on the start value (or the end value).  Your binary search will be a modified one — looking for the largest start value less than or equal to your given range's start value.  From there, you can determine whether the found range covers the given range or not.  Constant time isn't going to work; hashing doesn't help if the start of the given range isn't exactly the start of a range.

Comment: @nucandrei, no the input does not always belong to a range.

Comment: The duplicate has the non-overlapping ranges in the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

It's all about the data structure in which you store the information about the target ranges.  A data structure that affords O(1) solutions to your problem is possible, but not necessarily very attractive.  For example, we might construct an array having an entry for each (representable) value in the overall space that can be covered by any range of interest, and store in each element an index of the range, if any, that covers it.  Of course, that might require a vast amount of memory, and loading the target ranges into such a data structure would have a cost proportional to their size.

If you require a *compact* representation of the target ranges, and especially if you want one whose size is independent of the sizes of the ranges, then I don't think you can do better than by sorting the ranges by one endpoint, and using a binary search to locate target ranges.  That's equivalent to recording the ranges in a (balanced) binary search tree, and searching the tree for target ranges.  Given the appropriate data structure already constructed, the cost to solve the problem will be O(log n) in the number of target ranges.

Comment: Thanks for your input John!

Answer (score 2):

Constant time is possible for specific conditions: integer ranges with limited max value.

Make an array `A[0..Max]`, then fill it with range number for indexes in every range, and negative number of left range for empty spaces.

Ranges `[2,4], [7,10]` give array

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10   index
0  0  1  1  1  -1 -1 2  2  2  2    A[index]
```

Now for query `[3,5]` check array entries for both ends `A[3]` and `A[5]` and determine that left end lies inside 1-st range and right end lies in empty interval after 1-st range, so no other ranges are touched

Comment: Thanks for your input MBo!

Answer (score 0):

If ranges are only sorted, binary search is the best approach to find including range O(log n)

If you can define a function that applied to a specific range would return the position of that range in the collection and using the same function on input will return the position of the matching range in the collection, you could reduce the search to O(1)

E.g.

Given the following ranges

```
0-50, 51-100, 101-150, 150-200...
```

Find the range for the following input

```
130-140
```

We could devise a method

```
f(interval) {
   return interval.start / 50
}
```

that applied to (130-140) will give us position 2, and that's the one we are looking for

Comment: you can do better than binary search by just indexing every value in every range ...

Comment: That's right... if you have ranges smaller than the available memory

Comment: Thanks for your input nucandrei!

Answer (score 0):

Other answers suffice if the values in your ranges are bounded to some smallish range of values.

You can still do this in constant time if your input values are *not* bounded, but it's a lot more difficult, because you will have to make use of succinct data structures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succinct_data_structure

Sort your list of static ranges, and put the endpoints of all the static ranges into a succinct dictionary.  Then for any point integer `x` you can query `rank(x)` in constant time to get the number of end points less then `x`.  This is an index into your sorted list that points at the only range that could possibly contain `x`.

So for any input range, get the range that might contain its start point, and just check to see if it contains the input range, all in constant time.

Comment: Thanks for your input Matt!